# Python outputting as plain text win 7

Tags: python, apache, windows-7

I have installed Apache 32 bit  and Python 2.7 on Windows 7.
I have downloaded correct file (32 bit) mod_wsgi from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi).

When I restart Apache server the monitor shows:
Apache 2.2.25 (Win32) mod_wsgi / 3.5-BRANCH Python/2.7

Still when I run the following script saved as test.py

```
print "hii"
```

it just outputs plain text:
print "hii"

Comment: what did you expect? print... prints

Comment: I expected just "hii"
not
"print hii"

Comment: That's not how WSGI works.

Comment: Now I see it! How are you executing the file? Are you using a framework or something?

Comment: @Alvaro: No. They're serving up the raw file.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but it seemed rude to ask xD

Comment: Can anyone plz elaborate?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wsgi+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to use wsgi. WSGI is a standard interface for python applications to manage requests.
You can read about it [here](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I suggest you start out with some framework that will handle this for you, though.
For example [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)